# Remove Tables from Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, rails-migrations

This is probably a fairly basic question, but I'm at a loss on how to clean up after installing a gem I decided not to use.  During the install process of [Attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary), the install instructions said to run `rake attachinary:install:migrations` - creating a new table and index in my schema, noted here:

```
create_table "attachinary_files", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "attachinariable_id"
    t.string   "attachinariable_type"
    t.string   "scope"
    t.string   "public_id"
    t.string   "version"
    t.integer  "width"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.string   "format"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

add_index "attachinary_files", ["attachinariable_type", "attachinariable_id", "scope"], name: "by_scoped_parent", using: :btree
```

I later decided to go with a simplier attachement gem and I'm attempting to clean up and remove all the "stuff" created during the attachinary install.

Any advice on how to clean up the db?  I'm running Postgresql if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a migration:

```
bundle exec rails g migration remove_attachinary
```

Then tell Rails what to do:

```
def up
  drop_table :attachinary_files
end
```

Remove the `change` method present by default

If ever you'd like this migration to be reversible, copy your previous code in a `down` method